# leading zero insert/update issue in python and postgresql

Tags: postgresql, python-3.6

I'm trying to insert **empid** into my Postgres table, issue here is I'm seeing the leading zero is missing in all cases. How could i retain it ?

my python code:

```
sql = "insert into emp (empid,name,sal) values (%s,%s,%s)"
data = (05599,xyz,10000)
cur.execute(sql, data)
```

Postgresql column datatype

```
empid --> character varying(5)
```

in the table I'm seeing only 5599 instead of 05599. How could I retain the leading zero while inserting/updating data into the table?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know Python, but it sounds as if the values are sent as numbers to the database, not as strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how you got that code to work:

```
create table emp (empid varchar ,name varchar, sal numeric);
import psycopg2
con = psycopg2.connect("dbname=test host=localhost user=aklaver")
cur = con.cursor()
sql = "insert into emp (empid,name,sal) values (%s,%s,%s)"

data = (05599,xyz,10000)
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid token

# This works

data = ('05599', 'xyz' ,10000)
cur.execute(sql, data)
con.commit()

select * from emp;
 empid | name |  sal  
-------+------+-------
 05599 | xyz  | 10000
```

So as @a_horse_with_no_name suggested pass in as a string.